# Javascript game project javascript/database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, database

I'm trying to make a little online game using javascript and php.

The point is that I dont want to ever refresh the page. I want to make it kinda 'realtime gameplay', but I encountered a serious problem.
I successfully made a database, but I want to update player location everytime he moves on the map.

I just want some kind of AJAX/javascript that is changing the player location value from database with new one  everytime the player moves; I dont want to use buttons, forms, or other pages; I just want some kind of help making a script that updates player location into a MySQL database every 30 seconds.

Heres the javascript with player movement

```
//player movement here
    engine.player.move = function(direction)
    {

       var index, x, y;

       index = x = y = 0;

       engine.keyboard.canInput = false;

       switch(direction)
       {
          case 'up':    index = 0;  y =  1;     break;
          case 'right': index = 3;  x = -1;     break;
          case 'left':  index = 9;  x =  1;     break;
          case 'down':  index = 6;  y = -1;     break;

       }

       var toX = engine.viewport.x + (engine.screen.tilesX / 2 - 0.5) - x;
       var toY = engine.viewport.y + (engine.screen.tilesY / 2 - 0.5) - y;
       var toTile = engine.map.get(toX, toY);

       if(engine.tile.hasProperty(toTile, 'solid', 1) ||
          engine.npc.isNpcAt(toX, toY))
       {
          engine.keyboard.canInput = true;
       }else{
          engine.viewport.playerOffsetX = x * Math.ceil(5 / 16 * engine.tileSize);
          engine.viewport.playerOffsetY = y * Math.ceil(5 / 16 * engine.tileSize);

          setTimeout(engine.player.animate, engine.player.speed / 2);
          setTimeout(engine.player.reset, engine.player.speed);
       }

       engine.player.spriteIndex = index;
       engine.draw();
       engine.output('player  walks ' + toX + 'x' + toY + 'y');

    };
```

This is where i want to make the mysql update

```
   switch(direction)
       {
          case 'up':    index = 0;  y =  1; if(Y++){update player Y+1}      break;
          case 'right': index = 3;  x = -1;     break;
          case 'left':  index = 9;  x =  1;     break;
          case 'down':  index = 6;  y = -1;     break;

       }
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried and we will help you figure out why it won't work. We aren't just going to write the code for you.

Comment: http://oi42.tinypic.com/9jogi8.jpg this is the game itself, the players has his x,y coordinates saved in the mysql database,the problem is i dont really know how to make an active ajax connection to database wich saves the new x and y of the player if he move in other location

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never start the day without jquery. Try the post function. I'm not able to give you complete solution, but here's a key:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function userMove() {
     var data = {
         yourData1: value,
         ...
     }

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: your_file.php,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
     });
  }
</script>
```

[jquery $.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).

Instead of using a generic `SELECT/FROM/WHERE` query form, you can use [UPDATE/SET/WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Answer (score 0):

i am thinking of making a GET position variable in php that 'gets' the user location from javascript but im not sure if this is posible in any way.